# Copy Excel table to PowerPoint via VBA and save

Tags: excel, vba, com, powerpoint, ole

I am trying to mass-generate a series of PowerPoint presentations. My slide would contain two elements, both created and copied from Excel. I am using Office 2010.

The first element is a SmartArt graphic which is smoothly done. The second one is a few cells that I would like to **copy as a Table object** (instead of a linked image). After wasting a few hours with "Shapes", I found this, but I cannot **manipulate its height and width** after pasting.

```
PPApp.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteSourceFormatting")
```

Then, when I tried to save the presentation using the following, I realised only the SmartArt is saved; the pasted table is not saved even though the saveAs command occured **after** the paste.

```
PPApp.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteSourceFormatting")
PPPres.SaveAs saveName, ppSaveAsDefault
PPPres.Close
```

More bizarrely, I found that when I added a msgbox command for debugging above between paste and save, the table is saved correctly. However, I am trying to mass produce these files and cannot sit down to close each message box.

My questions:
1. How can I change the table's height/width/alignment after pasting?
2. How can I save my file with the table in it?

**EDITED, my current code**

```
Sub copyAllToPpt()

Dim PPApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim PPPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim PPSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim PPName, xlName As String

xlName = ActiveWorkbook.Name
Dim saveName As String

Workbooks(xlName).Activate
Dim y As Integer
y = ActiveCell.Row
saveName = ActiveSheet.Cells(y, "B").Value & "-" & ActiveSheet.Cells(y, "A").Value & " Stats"

Set PPApp = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")
PPApp.Visible = True
Set PPPres = PPApp.Presentations.Add
PPName = PPPres.Name

PPApp.ActiveWindow.ViewType = ppViewSlide

Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides.Add(1, ppLayoutBlank)

createSmartArtGraphicThenCopy

PPSlide.Shapes.Paste.Select

PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Height = 288
PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Width = 641
PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignCenters, msoTrue
PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignMiddles, msoTrue
PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.Unselect
'Macro is working as expected up to here

Workbooks(xlName).Activate

createTable
'Table is copied in subroutine

PPApp.Activate

PPApp.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteSourceFormatting")
'Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
'Tried the Wait() to no avail.

DoEvents: DoEvents: DoEvents

PPApp.ActivePresentation.SaveAs saveName, ppSaveAsDefault
PPApp.ActivePresentation.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: as @steverindsberg suggests I think your problem is probably time.  Find some way of pausing for a few moments after  pasting the table and before saving and closing.  This is what you msgbox is doing or Steves doEvents.

Comment: Thanks. I tried using 3 'DoEvents' as advised. The system seems to randomly give either saved files sans table, or _Method 'SaveAs' of object '_Presentation' failed._ error.

Comment: Further update: I reordered the two elements so that the table would be pasted first in an attempt to deal with the time issue. Turns out the table still does not get pasted while the SmartArt is pasted smoothly. Watching the PPT window I noticed a long pause before a flash of the right click menu. After the file is saved and closed by VBA, there is still sans table.

Answer (score 3):

This works when I run it from within PPT; you'll need to adapt it by adding references to the PPT application object, etc:

```
Dim oSh As Object
Dim oSl As Object
Dim x As Long

x = 1 ' or whatever slide you want to work with

Set oSl = ActivePresentation.Slides(x)

CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteSourceFormatting")
DoEvents: DoEvents: DoEvents

Set oSh = oSl.Shapes(oSl.Shapes.Count)

oSh.Left = 0
' etc
```

Without the DoEvents statements, it fails, in exactly the same way as your save problem fails.  Unless you give PPT a few cycles to deal with the newly pasted shape, it thinks that it's not there.

Comment: Thanks, but I got "Run-time error 429, ActiveX component can't create object" on the "Set oSh" line. The paste did not take place. Advise please?
Also, doesn't MetafilePicture just paste as image? How can I paste it as a editable table instead? Thanks again.

Comment: You'd need to preface any commands to PowerPoint with PPApp, as in the partial code you posted earlier and if using early binding would need to Dim oSh as PowerPoint.Shape or similar.  I'd try with it dimmed as Object as a test.

Comment: Thanks. It seems to alleviate some errors. However now I am getting "Method 'SaveAs' of object '_Presentation' failed."

Comment: Also, would it be possible to paste as a Table instead of a picture? The latter is what I am getting with "MetafilePicture".

Comment: Again, see edited answer.  It's giving me a table here.

Comment: Steve, I can now see the table pasted, but get _Shapes.Item: Integer out of range. 0 is not in Index's valid range of 1 to 0_ on the line 'Set oSh = oSl.Shapes(oSl.Shapes.Count)'
(Sorry admin, I do not have enough reputation to move to discussion)

Comment: Try adding more DoEvents after pasting. I've run into odd situations where it take as many as five to get reliable results on some PCs.  Until I added them in the code I posted, I was getting the same "Integer out of range" error.  Odd, that.  It's a Long, not an integer;  Ah well.  No MS error message is allowed to ship until a bit of misleading nonsense has been folded in.

Comment: Thanks and will try that tonight! Could you explain the purpose of the Shapes.count line? That I do not understand. Thanks again.

Comment: In order to get a reference to the just-pasted-in shape, we want to grab the last shape in the slide's shapes collection, which'd be the shape with the highest index; that'll always be the one equal to the number of shapes on the slide, hence Shapes.Count

Comment: Thanks. Even with 5 DoEvents I am still getting the "Integer out of range" on oSl.Shapes.Count line, and my computer really isn't slow... Edit: now I am getting "Object variable or With block variable not set"